# query_posts pagination will always show identical content

Tags: query-posts, pagination, next-post-link, previous-post-link

Anyone here see why my pagination won't work? I can get "previous page" to show up, but when navigating to "page-2", the content will stay identical to the content on "page-1".

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Generic Trips Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( "beforeloop", "page" ) ?>
                                    <?php $types = $post->post_name; ?>


 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
     <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'trips', 'types' => $types, "posts_per_page" => 5)); ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post">


                        </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) : ?>
                           <div class="pnavi">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
                           </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries')); ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;')); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


                  <?php get_template_part( "afterloop", "page" ) ?> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [query_posts and pagination, still stuck after much research](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52716/query-posts-and-pagination-still-stuck-after-much-research)

Comment: Please **search the site** before posting new questions. This particular question has been asked [*over and over and over again*...](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query_posts+pagination)

Comment: @ChipBennett : none of the answers I found this far solved my specific problem.

Comment: @WouterB Explain in detail what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use `query_posts`!](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/9364)

As Eugene pointed out, you omitted the `paged` variable. However, even with that in you can get unexpected behaviour. As illustrated by the various questions we get on `query_posts` and pagination:

- [query_posts and pagination, still stuck after much research](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52716/query-posts-and-pagination-still-stuck-after-much-research)
- [Pagination throws 404](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21856/pagination-throws-404)
- [Pagination throws 404 error on custom taxonomy archive pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45772/pagination-throws-404-error-on-custom-taxonomy-archive-pages)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `paged` argument to `query_posts` call. It should look like this:

```
<?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'trips', 
        'types' => $types, 
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged,
    ) );
?>
```

Read more about [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in codex, especially [pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) section.

Comment: @EugeneManilov Good catch. Unfortunately that didn't help.